# How to lock screen orientation for the iPad SwiftUI

Tags: swift, ipad, swiftui, orientation, screen-orientation

I've been force locking the screen orientation using this, which works fine on iPhone simulators:

```
@main
struct MainApp: App {
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }
}
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {

static var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return AppDelegate.orientationLock
}
}
```

And used on a view like so:

```
struct ContentView : View {
var body : some View {
ZStack {
Text("Hello World!")
                        .onAppear{
                                           UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
                        AppDelegate.orientationLock = .portrait
                    }.onDisappear{
                        UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
                        AppDelegate.orientationLock = .portrait
                    }
}
}
}
```

However, this doesn't work on iPad simulators. It is not enough to deselect orientations in target's Deployment Info because some views have to be different orientations.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it what you want to authorise all orientation ? You use UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all

Comment: @PtitXav no I want to lock a specific view one way and then a different view in navigation another way. I.e. Content View would have to be portrait and can't be landscape but another view you navigate to from Content View would have to be landscape and can't be portrait.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your project on the left section in Xcode and then you can scroll down till you see "Deployment info". From there you can lock the app screen orientation both in iPhone and iPad
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't lock specific views in navigation each to a specific orientation, just determines what orientations are supported by the app.